# Is that going to be a scam and who has been hacked?

Tags: scams

A friend received this probably fraud email and asked me several questions about it:

> Coucou, mon message est-il parvenu?

Which is French (we are French) for:

> Hi, is my message arrived?

There was no attached content to this short email.

The two questions my friend asks:

What does the sender is trying to do? Gain confiance with an answer?

**Most importantly, who was hacked? The relative of my friend who the hacker falsely uses his name with a similar and wrong email address, my friend who the hacker knows the email, both of them, or none of them?**

I saw many interesting questions about scams in finance.SE, which were often related to illegally get money, and there is a tag scams, but if you think my question is not appropriate because this is not scam (are at least unless my friend answers), or this is not related to personal finance yet, or something else I missed, please pardon me for asking the wrong place!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's a scammer looking for live and gullible email addresses

Nobody has been hacked. They scrape addresses off the internet, or sometimes just do a brute-force send to every possible userid.

Ignore it. If it came with an attachment, do not open that attachment.

Consider tightening up your spam filters, if you have any control of that.

Welcome to the modern Internet. This nonsense is going to continue until we switch to a security -oriented mail framework.

Comment: Do you know how he knew the name of my friend's relative? And create a similar but fake email with the name?

Comment: @JKHA someone's contact list leaked? some email was forwarded to the wrong place and was harvested? Possibilities are endless.

Comment: Messages like "Is this you in the video (or picture)?' are common too. The idea is to get you to click the link. In the absence of a link, There could be a 'web bug', I guess, although many email clients block download of images and you have to explicitly agree to download them. A web bug is a small e.g. 1x1 pixel transparent embedded image hosted somewhere under the control of the sender, who can examine their web log to see what IP address downloaded it, and add it to a list of potentially poorly secured people.